# What subjects are required for studying classical field theory?

Tags: classical-field-theory

I'm a undergraduate (sophomore) physics student who wants to study *The Classical Theory of Fields* by Landau & Lifshitz.
What subject are required for studying this book/topic?

I have already studied

- classical dynamics (Fowles, Landau)
- electrodynamics (not whole topics, just electrostatics, magnetostatics and E or M field in matter)
- quantum mechanics (Griffiths ~ch.4)
- special relativity
- statistical mechanics and thermal physics

The mathematics I have studied are

- calculus
- differential equations (ordinary and partial)
- linear algebra
- variational calculus
- complex analysis (until the residue theorem)
- a little about tensors (I'm not studied this detail. I just studied for special relativity)

Are there any other topics which I must learn?

Comment: Probably the most important things are being comfortable with the idea of a field (which it seems you are), and the methods of Lagrangian mechanics (mostly basic variatioa calculus, Noether's theorem, functional differentiation). Other than that, just go for it.

Comment: @BobKnighton  Thanks for your comment. According to your advice, I think I can start it.  :)

Comment: Given this is vol.2 of the course, you should be *immensely* comfortable with the contents of vol.1, which is “Mechanics”.